# Splitting of the ring class group of an imaginary quadratic field

Tags: field-theory, algebraic-number-theory, class-field-theory

Let $K$ be an imaginary quadratic field, $\mathcal{O}_K$ be its ring of integers and $\mathcal{O}(n)$ be an order of $K$ of conductor $n\in\mathbb{N}$. It is known that there is a surjection between class groups

$Cl(\mathcal{O}(n))\twoheadrightarrow Cl(\mathcal{O}_K)$.

My question is the following: is it possible (in some cases) to find a splitting of this surjection, or, more weakly, is it possible for $Cl(\mathcal{O}_K)$ to be (isomorphic to) a subgroup of $Cl(\mathcal{O}(n))$?

Comment: Not too hard if $O_K$ is a PID. Being isomorphic to a subgroup is always the case and that's not enough for a splitting.

Comment: Ok, maybe let's stay in the nontrivial case when $\mathcal{O}_K$ is not a PID. Is it true in this case that $Cl(\mathcal{O}_K)$ is always isomorphic to a subgroup of $Cl(\mathcal{O}(n))$?

Comment: Sure as in any surjective homomorphism of finite abelian groups

Comment: But indeed the splitting is not always there, right?

Comment: Yes splitting is $Cl(O(n))=Cl(O_K)\oplus H$ not always the case. With $O_K=\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$ it is the case with $O(n)=\Bbb{Z}[3\sqrt{-5}]$ but not $O(n)=\Bbb{Z}[2\sqrt{-5}]$